# Vector Quantization+Som+show sub image with determined labels

Tags: image, matlab, som

i wrote a code that read image and cluster with vector Quantization learned with Som network,now i have coodbook matrix , how can i show sub images of original image with determined coodbook

Comment: Kindly provide your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifable example to allow people to understand where is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: did you saved the index or min x,y and the height and width??